# What's the real style when multiple CSS style classes are applied to the same element?

Tags: css

I have a html file as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .social { color: red; border: 1px solid blue; display: inline-block;}
        .first { color: green; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="social">taco</p>
        <p class="first">burrito</p>
        <p class="first social">chimichanga</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I uses classes 'first' and 'social' for the 3rd paragraph. However, the colour of the 3rd paragraph is always green ('first') no matter whether I put 'first' before 'social' or after.

So, how does the browser decide the css style when multiple style classes are applied to one element?

Comment: `no matter whether I put 'first' before 'social' or after` ... Are you referring to order in the `<style>` tag or the application of those styles?

Comment: Of cause, it's the order in the element.

Comment: Have a look at this article - it outlines in which order css directives are applied. https://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

Comment: For me this one was enlightening read https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [CSS2.1 specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade):

> Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins.

In your case, the `first` class appears after the `social` class in your internal stylesheet. Since both have the same weight, origin, and specificity, the `first` rule's overlapping style (i.e., color property) wins.

Answer (score 3):

It is green simply because class `.first` is the last in the order of css selectors which applied for this element. So if you swap them it will become red. (`.social` after `.first`)

The reference order in the class attribute does not make any effect.

[Here](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm) is quite long and old but good read about how browsers works and especially how css computation works.